# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to resolve :

```py
train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = {'x': train_x},
        y = train_y,
        batch_size = 100 , 
        num_epochs = None , 
        shuffle = True
        )
detector.train(input_fn = train_input_fn , steps = 1 , hooks = [logging_hook])
```

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Answer (score 0):

From the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/inputs/pandas_input_fn),

it says `x` should be a pandas dataframe.
try

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( { 'x':train_x } )
```